# Command-line utility for WebDAV upload

Tags: webdav

I need a command-line utility that can do WebDAV upload (HTTP PUT).

Comment: I gathered a list of CLI tools https://github.com/stokito/awesome-webdav/blob/main/readme.md#cli
Also check my WebDAV with curl https://gist.github.com/stokito/cf82ce965718ce87f36b78f7501d7940

Answer (score 108, accepted):

[cURL](http://curl.haxx.se/) will do it for you.

```
curl -T filetoput.xml http://www.url.com/filetoput.xml
```

Working example:

```
curl -T pic.jpg -u me@example.com:longapppass https://webdav.cloud.server.com:443
```

Comment: In case of WebDAV your example will not work without a very tiny but important detail -> include name of the file you want to have on remote. So : curl -T filetoput.xml http://www.url.com/filetoput.xml

Comment: @Cninroh: I don't believe that's true. According to the curl manpage: "If there is no file part in the specified URL, Curl will append the local file name. NOTE that you must use a trailing / on the last directory  to really prove to Curl that there is no file name or curl will think that your last directory name is the remote file name to use."

Comment: +1, cURL for the win. And if you need to authenticate, you can use `curl -T <filename> -u <username>:<password> <url>`.

Comment: you can also use `-o /dev/stdout` to get a progress output

Comment: genius master geeks

Comment: Actually, omitting the file part from the destination URL results in HTTP Error 409 CONFLICT in case the target server is an IIS server at least up to and including IIS 10. Maybe IIS is in the wrong though and it should work per the specs, just saying.

Comment: results in `400 Bad request` for the fastmail webdav endpoint `https://myfiles.fastmail.com/`

Answer (score 17):

For unix (and Windows with [Cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/) installed) you can use [Cadaver](http://www.webdav.org/cadaver/)

Comment: You can't tell cadaver to upload a set of files from the command line; you need to type in the `put` commands in it's own repl ... this approach is copied from ftp tools, but makes the tool useless for composing as part of another script.

Answer (score 9):

The most commonly used command line HTTP utility seems to be [cURL](http://curl.haxx.se/), which will do `PUT` with its [-T option](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html#-T).  You would need to understand quite a bit of the WebDAV protocol to do more than upload with it, though.

Answer (score 8):

If you need to upload the entire directory instead of one file over WebDAV, you can use the following approach.

Imagine you have the following local folder you're going to upload over WebDAV.

```
local_folder_to_upload
│   test.txt
│   test1.txt    
│
└───nested_folder1
│   │   file1.txt
│   │   file2.txt
│   │
│   └───nested_folder2
│       │   file11.txt
│       │   file12.txt
```

1.First you need to create nested directories from your local folder (if you have them) on a server. Since WebDAV doesn't support recursive upload, you have to do this in separate step ([if you were to use `ftp`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14020013/3006185) - you would add `--ftp-create-dirs` flag to do this). To create those folders over WebDAV you need to use [MKCOL method](https://greenbytes.de/tech/webdav/rfc4918.html#METHOD_MKCOL).

```
curl -X MKCOL 'http://your.server/uploads/nested_folder1' --user 'name:pwd'
curl -X MKCOL 'http://your.server/uploads/nested_folder1/nested_folder2' --user 'name:pwd'
```

Please note that you can't create them in one request according [to the spec](https://greenbytes.de/tech/webdav/rfc4918.html#rfc.section.9.3.p.1).

> if a request to create collection /a/b/c/d/ is made, and
>   /a/b/c/ does not exist, the request must fail.

2.Second you can utilize output of [find](https://www.linode.com/docs/tools-reference/tools/find-files-in-linux-using-the-command-line/) shell command to upload it to your server using `curl`.

```
cd local_folder_to_upload && find . -exec curl -T {} 'http://your.server/uploads/{}' --user 'name:pwd' \;
```

Code above loop over all your files inside given directory (using find) and add the output (file name with relative path) to the placeholder `{}` in the url of your webserver. So it makes multiple requests (one per each file), and since all nested folders were created in advance - those requests shouldn't fail.

Hope it's helpful to someone.

Answer (score 6):

Free [WinSCP](https://winscp.net/) (for Windows) supports WebDAV (and WebDAVS).
WinSCP supports scripting/command-line operations too.

Sample WinSCP script to upload a file over WebDAV:

```
open https://user@webdav.example.com/
put file.txt /path/
exit
```

Save the script to a file (e.g. `script.txt`) and run like:

```
winscp.com /script=script.txt
```

You can also put everything on a single line:

```
winscp.com /command "open https://user@webdav.example.com/" "put file.txt /path/" "exit"
```

Start with [introduction to scripting with WinSCP](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/guide_automation).

You can even have [WinSCP GUI generate the script file for you](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/guide_automation#generating).

*(I'm the author of WinSCP)*

Answer (score 5):

Another option is "davix"

https://davix.web.cern.ch/davix/docs/devel/

It can be installed with

`sudo yum install davix` (redhat)
or
`sudo apt install davix` (ubuntu)

it has separated utils like davix-mkdir davix-put etc
You can specify creditions in URL like

```
 davix-mkdir http://user:passw@example.com/dir_to_create
 davix-put local_file http://user:passw@example.com/dir_to_create/remote_file_name
```

Answer (score 4):

To do WebDAV recursive upload of an arbitrary directory structure (files inside folders inside folders, etc.), the tool [Rclone](https://rclone.org/) worked for me.

Based on [this answer on SuperUser](https://superuser.com/a/1338299/915486), I was able to recursively copy a directory by doing the following:

1. Configure the connection:

   ```
    rclone config create my-remote webdav \
        url https://my-webdav-server/my-dir/ \
        vendor other \
        user 'username'

    rclone config password pass 'mypasswd'
   ```
2. Copy:

   ```
   rclone copy /home/me/mydir my-remote:
   ```

Rclone offers a number of other modes of dealing with files, including `sync`, which brings the remote in line with the local copy by removing remote files not present locally (in addition to copying local files across that do not exist remotely). See the [subcommands of Rclone](https://rclone.org/docs/#subcommands) for more information.

Answer (score 3):

[this overview](http://www.ics.uci.edu/~ejw/authoring/implementation.html) contains a thourough list of webdav server and clients.

I'd opt for cadaver or, if my needs were very specific, a python script using the [PyWebDAV](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/PyWebDAV/0.9.3) library.

Answer (score 3):

Use KIO under KDE:

```
kioclient cp file.txt 'webdavs://user@webdav.example.com:443/'
```

Answer (score 0):

Teleric Fiddler has a "compose" tab where you can create your 
own customized WebDAV request. E.g. PROPFIND and OPTIONS etc.