# Uploading all of files in my local directory with curl

Tags: shell, curl, ftp, terminal

I want to upload all the files in one directory, and I know how to upload one file using curl like this :

```
curl -T "local/xxx.suffix" -u xxx:psw "ftp://192.168.1.158/public/demon_test/xxx.suffix"
```

How can I upload all the files (subdirectory) in the current directory to an FTP server?

Answer (score 79, accepted):

Use `curl` with `find` to recursively upload all files from a specific directory:

```
find mydir -type f -exec curl -u xxx:psw --ftp-create-dirs -T {} ftp://192.168.1.158/public/demon_test/{} \;
```

Comment: How can i enhance this command line to get the filename of each uploaded file?

Comment: how could I do this without uploading the original folder but just it's contents?

Comment: @ProblemsOfSumit Then you just need to remove the last {} from the url

Comment: I don't think this is an optimal solution for uploading several files, as `curl` will disconnect after every file upload and reconnect again for the next file, which will slow down the process terribly

Answer (score 7):

instead of curl, use wput (not to be confused with wget).

Comment: Nonetheless a very useful answer.

Comment: an example would help