# How to specify putting zip into jfrog artifactory?

Tags: artifactory

I have directory like `/tmp/some-js/(a lot of folders)`

I added it into zip `/tmp/some-js.zip`

I have structure in artifactory like `/npm-dev/some-js/*`

I put into artifactory this zip with command

`curl -u user:api-key -k -X PUT https://xxx.xx.xx.xx:8081/artifactory/npm_dev/some-js/ -T /tmp/some-js.zip`

And I have got directory in artifactory `/npm-dev/some-js/some-js.zip/*`

There is a way to specify unpacking `some-js.zip` contents into `/npm-dev/some-js` ?

Comment: Seems duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40477093/how-to-upload-entire-directory-to-artifactory-in-linux-using-curl-or-any-shell-s. You can add a header to extract the content of the zip file during upload, by adding X-Explode-Archive: true

Comment: @Tom.A thank you! I didn't find this post. Should i delete this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to upload entire directory to artifactory in Linux using curl or any shell script or any commandline utility in Linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40477093/how-to-upload-entire-directory-to-artifactory-in-linux-using-curl-or-any-shell-s)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Uploading an archive file (such as a zip file) to Artifactory and extracting its content to a specific directory is done by:

```
PUT https://<jfrog-platform>/artifactory/the-repo/path/to/dir/file.zip
X-Explode-Archive: true

<file-content>
```

The content of `file.zip` will be extracted and deployed under `the-repo/path/to/dir/`, preserving the relative directory structure in the zip file. So if `file.zip` has the following structure:

```
foo/
  |- bar.txt
  |- baz.txt
```

The following files will be created in Artifactory:

```
the-repo/path/to/dir/foo/bar.txt
the-repo/path/to/dir/foo/baz.txt
```

Using `curl` and the details in the question:

```
curl -u user:api-key \
     -k \
     -X PUT \
     https://xxx.xx.xx.xx:8081/artifactory/npm_dev/some-js/some-js.zip \
     -T /tmp/some-js.zip
     -H "X-Explode-Archive: true"
```

For more information, see the documentation on [Deploy Artifacts from Archive](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Artifactory+REST+API#ArtifactoryRESTAPI-DeployArtifactsfromArchive)