# curl + ftp for directory containing files and directories

Tags: shell, curl, scripting, ftp, travis-ci

I am trying to write a script that will help me upload a directory to a FTP location.

The directory structure looks like so:

```
MasterDirectory/
    file1.jpg
    file2.jpg
    ChildDirectory/
        childFile.jpg
```

Ideally, I want to write a shell script that does the following:

- `cd MasterDirectory/`
- iterate through all contents
- if there is a file, upload that file with `curl -T filename` and FTP
- if there is a directory, upload that directory and all of its contents, including any subdirectories

I am able to upload a single file with the command `curl -T filename.jpg ftp://ftp.server.com --user username:password` but past that, I am a bit lost. Can anyone show me what kind of script I would write to accomplish this?

I want this script to run in the `after-success` node of a Travis CI job. I am not married to the idea of using a shell script, but this feels like the best way to do this. If anyone has a better idea for doing this with Travis CI, I am open to suggestion!

Thank you so much in advance for any help you can provide!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The outcome of this use case is much like [a previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14019890/uploading-all-of-files-in-my-local-directory-with-curl) . If you're ok with running a single line of code instead of writing a script, you should be able to accomplish the goal using:

`find MasterDirectory -type f -exec curl --user username:password --ftp-create-dirs -T {} ftp://ftp.server.com/{} \;`