# Gitlab-ci cannot upload all .js file to JFrog

Tags: curl, gitlab-ci, artifactory

I tried to upload all .js file from Gitlab-ci to Jfrog and I got this

> curl: Can't open 'scripts/*.js'

It works if I point to a specified file (scripts/001.js)

My .gitlab-ci.yml

```
---
default:
  image:
    name: ubuntu:18.04
    entrypoint:
      - '/usr/bin/env'
      - 'PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin'

stages:
  - upload

job01:
  only:
    - branches
  stage: upload
  script:
    - apt update -y
    - apt install curl -y
    - curl -u $JFROG_USERNAME:$JFROG_PASSWORD -X PUT $JFROG_URL -T 'scripts/*.js'

  tags:
    - runner-aws
```

I tried with 'scripts/(*).js' and the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `curl` doesn't support wildcard character expansion in the `-T` option. This answer summarizes it nicely: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/315431

So the solution would be to either enumerate multiple files like this:

```
   - curl -u $JFROG_USERNAME:$JFROG_PASSWORD -X PUT $JFROG_URL -T "scripts/{file1.js,file2.js,file3.js}"
```

But if there are too many files to enumerate, or the file names can change, you can use `curl` in combination with `find` (inspired by https://stackoverflow.com/a/14020013/7109330):

```
   - find scripts -type file -name "*.js" -exec curl -u $JFROG_USERNAME:$JFROG_PASSWORD -X PUT $JFROG_URL -T {} \;
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend using the [JFrog CLI](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/CLI/JFrog+CLI) to upload files to Artifactory. It works much faster than curl by uploading files in parallel and avoiding uploading files that already exist in Artifactory.

It is also support wildcard patterns:

```
jfrog rt u "scripts/*.js" <path/in/artifactory> --user=$JFROG_USERNAME --password=$JFROG_PASSWORD --url=https://jfrog-platform-url/artifactory
```

Read more under [Uploading Files](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/CLI/CLI+for+JFrog+Artifactory#CLIforJFrogArtifactory-UploadingFiles).

Comment: Thanks, I'm able to use cli, just want to do it with curl.