# Cadaver bash script upload

Tags: bash, shell, webdav, cadaver

Please note: I need to insert some spaces in URLs, because of the restrictions of StackOverflow.

I have a FreeBSD server. I need to backup my previously tar.gz databases on a WebDav cloud storage as Yandex Disk or Box.com or 4Shared.

Everything works fine with Putty, command line after command line. I am be able to upload my file on Yandex Disk:

```
%cadaver  
dav:!> open https://webdav.yandex.com  
Authentication required for Yandex.Disk on server `webdav.yandex.com':
Username: MyUserName
Password:
dav:/> put MyFile.tar.gz
Uploading MyFile.tar.gz to `/MyFile.tar.gz':  
Progress: [=============================>] 100.0% of 1229518 bytes succeeded.
dav:/> exit  
Connection to ` webdav . yandex . com' closed.  
%
```

However, my bash script fails to upload my file.

Here is my bash script "criptdav.sh":

```sh
#!/bin/sh

/usr/local/bin/cadaver < datadav
```

Here is my "datadav" file:

```
open https:// webdav . yandex . com  
MyUserName  
MyPassword  
put MyFile.tar.gz  
exit
```

Here is Putty screenshot of my bash script:

```
%sh scriptdav.sh  
dav:!> open https://webdav.yandex.com  
Authentication required for Yandex.Disk on server `webdav.yandex.com': 
Username: MyUserName
dav:/> 
Connection to `webdav.yandex.com' closed.  
%
```

Nota Bene:

I tried with Yandex, Box, 4Shared. Same result. Script fails to upload my file.

**QUESTION:**

**What's wrong with my bash script?**

Comment: Thank you to S K who edited my message, however, my "Putty screenshots" are broken now, so nobody can understand them now.

Comment: One nitpick: A script starting with `#!/bin/sh`, or meant to be run with `sh yourscript` instead of `bash yourscript`, is not a bash script but a POSIX sh script. They're two different languages.

Comment: Anyhow --  haven't looked into cadaver specifically, but in general well-written software (from a security-best-practices perspective) won't accept passwords from stdin, but reads them from the TTY.

Comment: ...if you want a WebDAV client built for behaving well when scripted, I'd consider either `curl` (yes, it can be used for the purpose), or `lftp` (yes, despite having "FTP" in the name, it supports WebDAV).

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1205101/command-line-utility-for-webdav-upload

Comment: A full day of trying. Nothing works.

Comment: Speaking as someone who's done it successfully before -- with a medical records system using CaDAVer for file storage a decade ago -- it ain't that hard, but "nothing works" isn't enough to go on to debug. That said, if you were assuming that, say, passwords-on-stdin would work with every single piece of software you tried, it's entirely believable that every single one (or at least whatever subset was well-written re: security best practices) would fail.

Comment: I am sorry Charles, I am a big dummy. I work for a week on this script. I cannot succeed to upload my backups through WebDav, Curl, or SFTP. This is why I come at StackOverflow to get help. However, the sterile speeches of experts do not solve problems. Only concrete examples that work are able to solve problems. So, if you have a working bash script, please, share it with us. I thank you.

Comment: If you have a working reproducer for the situation -- for which the uses given in the linked question fail -- please, share it with me. I already linked you to a ticket full of examples that worked for *someone*. If they don't work for you, presumably you've got something a little different in your environment -- but without reproducer code for the server and authentication config, we can't repro that problem, so we can't tell *why* something that worked for someone else won't work for you.

Answer (score 4):

`cadaver` will take commands from a file specified by the `-r` flag, and it will pull credentials from a file in your home dir called `.netrc`

Create a .netrc file in your home with this in it

```
machine webdav.yandex.com
login MyUserName
password MyPassword
```

and call cadaver with this:

```
cadaver -r datadav https://webdav.yandex.com
```