# Upload file to sharepoint : VBA

Tags: vba, sharepoint, upload

When I use the below code, no file is copied into the sharepoint, but the code does not show an error. Can someone help me here ?

```
Dim SharepointAddress As String
Dim LocalAddress As String
Dim objNet As Object
Dim FS As Object

SharepointAddress= "\\xxxx\sites\xxx\xxx"            
' Where you will enter your location path
LocalAddress = "yourfile path\test.xlsx"                                    
' Where you will enter the file path, e.g.: Excel file
Set objNet = CreateObject("WScript.Network")
Set FS = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
If FS.FileExists(LocalAddress) Then
FS.CopyFile LocalAddress, SharepointAddress
End If
Set objNet = Nothing
Set FS = Nothing
```

Comment: can someone suggest some alternative method or help me solve this query

Comment: If this doesn't throw an error, are you sure that you are using the right path?

Comment: Yes benno..the file path is right ..Do I need to specify the name of the file while giving the local address path ?

Answer (score 0):

workaround 1 (use Shell to copy into WebDav dir):

```
Shell "cmd.exe /k net use x: http://spsite/doclib"
Shell "cmd.exe /k copy c:\file.doc x:"
Shell "cmd.exe /k net use x: /delete"
```

workaround 2:

use vba Shell with some console app to do it without net drive
for example WinSCP or DavCopy or Curl or even PowerShell (see [more](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1205101/command-line-utility-for-webdav-upload))